# Why my JQuery Iteration works very slow in IE Browser, but fast in Firefox Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written two kind of iteration with jquery. Both solutions worked very slow in Internet Explorer version < 10 (but normal in IE version 10) and always fast in all Firefox browser versions.

This is the first solution:

```
var array = jQuery('.mySelectElements');
var i = 0;

$.each(array, function(){
    var nameSelect = jQuery(this).attr("name");
    var htmlSelect = "[name=" + nameSelect + "]";            
    var titleAttribut =  jQuery(htmlSelect).find("option:selected").attr("title");

    if(titleAttribut != "" || titleAttribut != null){           
        var htmlSpanElement = jQuery("#" + "cont_id_" + (i + 1));                       
        jQuery(htmlSpanElement).append(titleAttribut);   
    }
    i++;
});
```

This is the second solution:

```
jQuery('.mySelectElements').each(function(i, item) {                        
    var nameSelect = jQuery(item).attr("name");
    var htmlSelect = "[name=" + nameSelect + "]";            
    var atitleAttribut =  jQuery(htmlSelect).find("option:selected").attr("title"); 

    var htmlSpanElement = jQuery("#" + "cont_id_" + (i + 1));   
    jQuery(htmlSpanElement).append(titleAttribut);      
});
```

I have stopped the time with suitable javascript code and i have seen, that both solution needs a lot of time in IE browser in relation to the firefox browser.

The code looks in my html dom for special select elements and want to iterate over that. For each select element, the current selected value was readed and was saved in a specific span element for this select element.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Many thanks for helping me !

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: First of all `jQuery(item)` in the first line of both functions already gives you the same collection you search for again in the third line with `jQuery(htmlSelect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can optimize your code a little bit:

```
var spans = jQuery('span.myContainers');
jQuery('.mySelectElements').each(function(i, item) {
    var titleAttribut = jQuery(item).find("option:selected").attr("title"); 
    var htmlSpanElement = spans[i + 1];   
    jQuery(htmlSpanElement).append(titleAttribut);      
});
```

This way the number of jQuery lookups (they cost a lot) is reduced.
It will work assuming that:
- you give your spans a class `myContainers`
- the number of these spans is equal or greater than the number of selects
- names of select elements are unique

**Older versions of IE have performance problems with their JS engine, so it will be still slower on these browsers but you will see the performance improvement.**

Answer (score 1):

It because internet explorer and firefox use different javascript engine...

Comment: But how can is solve my code problem / speed problem?

Comment: @Marwief don't use IE ;-)